# Assign FormGroup to a new FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I at run time assign a new FormGroup to an existing FormGroup.

Simplified example:

I have a main form Group that looks like this. It has a FormArray so that I can add additional FormGroups at run time

```
this.editForm = new FormGroup({
    'name': new FormControl('Lorem', Validators.required),
    'Info': new FormArray([])
  });
```

The FormGroups that get added into the FormArray look like this

```
return new FormGroup({
    someData: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    dynamicFormGroup: new FormGroup({})
  });
```

Now what I want to do is at run time assign a new FormGroup to the 'dynamicFormGroup', that is nested in the main editForm.

Essentially I want to do this, because this FormGroup will have an unknown amount of FormControls that get generated at run time as the user enters some data.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
var myNewFormGroup = this.InfoFormArray.controls[index].get('dynamicFormGroup') as FormGroup;

myNewFormGroup = new FormGroup({});

var fields = ['Field1', 'Field2'];

fields.forEach(f => myNewFormGroup.addControl(f, new FormControl(false)));
```

I dont get any errors, but when I log out the Form, the changes dont take effect and the FormGroup, 'dynamicFormGroup' remains and empty object eg '{}'

Is this the right approach to follow in such a scenario? If yes, how can I assign my newly generated FormGroup to it?

Comment: you are overwriting the myNewFormGroup and removing the reference you should comment out the part where you are doing ``myNewFormGroup = new FormGoup({});`` or user setControl instead if you want to reset the control.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I correctly understand your question. To add form group in to form array I would suggest you to create getter of this form array (**info** form control in your case) and when you will iterate over **fields** array, you will push formGroups with controls that you want. Example:

Create getter:

```
public get info() {
  return this.editForm.controls['Info']
}
```

Push form groups in to form array

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){}

this.fields.forEach((field) => {
  this.info.push(
   this.formBuilder.group({
      someData: [''],
      dynamicFormGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
        someOtherControl: ['']
      })
   })
  )
})
```